# Magento | Get the last status for any order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, frontend, order-status

We need to get the last status of the order on fly after the order is placed in the frontend.

Can you please help us in it?

Thanks

Comment: can you please explain your complete requirement? when you want to get the status of the order?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I need to get the status of the order after the payment process finished.

Comment: You mean after placing the order or whenever the payment is captured

Comment: Yes after placing the order

Answer (score 0):

To get latest status and comment you can use below code:

$order will be the order object

```
$order_histories = $order->getStatusHistories();

$latestOrderHistory = array_pop($order_histories);
$comment = $latestOrderHistory->getComment();
$status = $latestOrderHistory->getStatus();
```

or

```
$statusHistoryItem = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getFirstItem();    
$status = $statusHistoryItem->getStatusLabel();    
$comment = $statusHistoryItem->getComment();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in observer method and hook the observer to "sales_order_place_after" event.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$histories = $order->getStatusHistories();
/** @var OrderStatusHistoryInterface $caseCreationComment */
$latestHistoryComment = array_pop($histories);
$comment = $latestHistoryComment->getComment();
$status = $latestHistoryComment->getStatus();
```

Whenever the order is placed, above code will execute. I am not sure what you are going to do with the status further. If you just want to know the status, this is the procedure.